# Clickable listView not working

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I am pretty new to android and was working on clickable list view, problem i am encountering is, every this is working fine except neither the toast is being shown nor the output is shown in terminal window.
My listView dose not have any image child,its just texts in list form.Therefore,no problem of Focusability.
Here is my code

```
public class FavoritePage extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

private ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorite_page);
    DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(this);
    db.add_activity("");
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arr2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.simple_colum, db.getalllist());
    lv.setAdapter(arr2);
    db.del_activity("");


}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String data = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is my Toast message!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    System.out.println("***************************************************************" + data);
}}
```

Any idea why is it doing so..??

Comment: Well, first you have to set the listener to the listView. Something like : `lv.setOnItemClickListener(this)`. Add this in your onCreate() just below your `findViewById()` code

Comment: Thanks,it worked like a charm,do write your answer below so that i can mark it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first you have to set the listener to the listView. Something like : `lv.setOnItemClickListener(this)`.

Add this in your `onCreate()` just below your `findViewById()` code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the below code can help you :-

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {

                  String data = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is my Toast message!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    System.out.println("***************************************************************" + data);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing setting the `onItemClickListener`.

Add this line `lv.setOnItemClickListener(this)` after this line `lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);` in `onCreate` method.

Also, I would suggest using camelCase [style](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) when doing Java programming.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of implementing OnItemClickListener in the activity,you can try something like below

```
public class FavoritePage extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorite_page);
    DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(this);
    db.add_activity("");
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arr2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.simple_colum, db.getalllist());
    lv.setAdapter(arr2);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(clickListener);
    db.del_activity("");
}

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener clickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    }
};
```

}